# HPE Smart Array P410 - Replacing failed drive of a degraded mirror with a new one using ssacli with the failed drive kept connected?

Tags: linux, raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

A server is using attached drives without the HP hot-plug drive cage, with drives attached to P410 using two SFF8087 -> 4x SAS SFF8482 cables. I can add new drives while running, but cannot remove a specific drive (no way of IDing for now).

A mirror array is running degraded (one physical drive failed), the OK drive is quite old, I do not want to power off the machine to risk the sole OK drive not starting up.

```
ssacli ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 show

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)

   array A

      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 136.7 GB
         Fault Tolerance: 1
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 35132
         Strip Size: 128 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 128 KB
         Status: Interim Recovery Mode
         Caching:  Enabled
         Unique Identifier: xxxxxxx
         Disk Name: /dev/sda          Mount Points: None
         Logical Drive Label: xxxxxxxx     323A
         Mirror Group 0:
            physicaldrive 1I:0:1 (port 1I:box 0:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
         Mirror Group 1:
            physicaldrive 1I:0:2 (port 1I:box 0:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, Failed)
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache
```

Please would the ssacli tool allow removing the failed drive from the mirror, and adding a new drive (same size) attached to a different slot ID? I do not have a spare machine to test the commands, and cannot play with the existing server while it runs in the degraded state.

The assumed commands would be:

```
ssacli controller slot=1 array A remove drives=0:2
ssacli controller slot=1 array A add drives=0:3
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you do:

1. Run backup.
2. Make sure you can actually restore from your backup. See, lots of people don't test their backups and keep regretting after all.
3. Physically remove the disks from your server.
4. Attach disks to some other box and overwrite RAID signatures to make disks look alien to the RAID when you insert them back. For Windows the name of the utility is diskpart and for Linux it's wipefs.
5. Insert old disks coupled with the new ones into the server and configure a new RAID set.
6. Initialize RAID set, install OS, partitions, FS etc.

You're done!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My question was about replacing the drive in the array with the machine running and the failed drive being connected to the StartArray controller - a standard operation with software raids like MDADM, ZFS, etc.

Comment: If you need to have zero downtime you need to a) insert spare drive first, and b) eject faulty drive. Rebuild should start automatically.